# Redirect link with token to the correct page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i am implementing email verification on my website, i am sending a link/"token" to the user, how do i make it so that the link redirects to success/failed page, here is how am sending the link (i am using React on the front end if that matters)

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def sendmail(request):
    FRONTEND_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8000'
    token = get_random_string(length=32)

    verify_link = FRONTEND_URL + '/email-verify/' + token
    subject, from_email, to = 'Verify Your Email', 'my@email', request.data['to']
    html_content = render_to_string('verify_email.html', {'verify_link':verify_link, 'base_url': FRONTEND_URL})
    text_content = strip_tags(html_content)

    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()

    return JsonResponse({"message": "email sent"},status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: This is not an answer but it might spare someone work: the package https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ covers email verification amongst other features very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly a duplicate question. Still i am answering this one.

Django way of doing this -:

You can use [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) or [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
    
def render_resp():
    # Example
    return redirect('/url/to/redirect/to/')
```

React way of handling this scenario -:

You may find [this article on react-router-redirection](https://reactgo.com/react-router-redirection/) useful for redirecting the user to another page after getting a success/failure response.

If you find difficulty in understanding, do let me know.

### **EDIT (FROM COMMENTS):**

Kindly check this -  This will surely help - [Using database to store actual URL and random string value in a single mapping](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-a-url-shortener-with-django/)

Afterwards use URL Redirect method to route your request to the required view/method.

Comment: i know how to use redirect in both django and react,the problem is how do i make the randomly generated link redirect where i want

Comment: You can simply use string formatting like
'''
    return redirect(f'{dynamic_url}')
'''
Its that simple

Comment: Is there any list of urls you want to redirect your view to?
From which you want to select url randomly?

Comment: no there isn't it's randomly generated by now i found another way to do this whole confirmation email thing, but one solution i thought to this would be using regular expressions (didn't try it though)

Comment: Can you share the code where url is being generated randomly?

Comment: i'ts already in the main post: `token = get_random_string(length=32)`               `verify_link = FRONTEND_URL + '/email-verify/' + token`

Comment: Kindly check this - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-a-url-shortener-with-django/
 This will surely help. 
Idea is to - save both the actual url and the random string field url value to database and then use URL Redirect method to route your request to the required view/method.
Please accept the answer if this satisfies you.

Comment: yup that's what i was looking for, make it an answer (not a comment) and i'll accept it.